# When route params change what is the correct way to propagate updated inputs to children components

Tags: angular

Let's say I have a component `Main` and a children component `Children`. `Main` component is associated to a route. It retrieves its inputs from the `ActivatedRoute`

```
export class Main implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(d => {
      this.data1 = this.route.snapshot.data['data1'];
      this.data2 = this.route.snapshot.data['data2'];
      this.doSomething();
    });
  }
}
```

`Children` is a typical component with `@Input` and a `ngOnInit` method:

```
export class Children implements OnInit {
  @Input("data1")
  public data1;
  @Input("data2")
  public data2;

  ngOnInit() {
      // doSomething with data1 and data2 together
      this.doSomething();    
  }
}
```

What is the correct way to init `Children` with `data1` and `data2` when the component is initialized and so when the route data changed?

`Children` may be reused but not as a part of a route. Is there a way that does not involve a router abstraction leak to `Children` code ?

Comment: Do you just need a way to execute `Children.doSomething()` when data1 or data2 change ?

Comment: Yes, whatever the action is. Parent is updated, how to  cascade this update to the childrens. Maybe the `ngOnChanges` event

Comment: If you have subscribed to route and did not unsubscribe. No effort is needed provided you have subscribed inside ngOnChanges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data's fields are bind to a form, you can use the onChange event to call your `doSomething()` :

```
<input [(ngModel)]="data1" (change)="doSomething()">...
```

Otherwise you should use the `NgOnChange` hook :

```
export class Children implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    ...
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
      if(changes['data1']){
        doSomething();
      }
      ...
    }
}
```

View the details of component's lifecycle here :

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

Comment: what is the connection between the `<input>` and `ngOnChanges` ? `NgAfterViewChecked` cannot be an option, the performance hit will be blocker

Comment: Sorry `ngOnchange` is on a directive and `(change)` is just the javascript input `onChange` event. I'm editing, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the router events inside your children components, you can probably get away with just using a setter, and putting all your data fields inside one object(this way if you update data1 and data2 at the same time, you'll only get one update event).

```
export type DataType = { data1: any, data2: any };

export class Children {

  private _data: DataType;

  @Input()
  public set data(newData: DataType ) {
      this._data = newData;
      this.dataUpdated();
  }

  dataUpdated() {
      //do something with this._data;
  }

}
```

So whenever you change the data object you pass into your children, your children will update.

Comment: It will do the job but the abstraction leaks. I'm not fond of wrapping the parameters into a object.